# Laravel livewire not seeing render update after attach

Tags: laravel, render, laravel-livewire

I have a livewire component rendering two lists on a page.  I have a button on the left list to add that item to the right list (many to many) relation using attach.  This is working, but the right list isn't getting re-rendered.  When I then click a filter I have on the left list, the right list re-renders showing the newly attached item.  It seems like either render() isn't being called when I do the attach method, or it is taking another call to render to pick up the new relation?  I also tried calling $this->render from the attach method, but that didn't help.

```
public function render()
    {
        $items = item::with('status')
            ->where(function($query){
                $query->when(!empty($this->selectedStati), function ($query) {
                    $query->whereHas('status', function ($query) {
                        $query->whereIn('id', $this->selectedStati);
                    })->orWhereDoesntHave('status');
                });
            })
            ->get();

        $testItems = $this->test->items;
       //dd($testItems);
        return view('livewire.items-source', [
            'selectedStati' => $this->selectedStati,
            'statuses' => $this->status,
            'items' => $items,
            'testItems' => $testItems
    ]);
    }

    public function filterStatus($id){
        if (($key = array_search($id, $this->selectedStati)) !== false) {
            unset($this->selectedStati[$key]);
        } else {
            $this->selectedStati[]=$id;
        }
        session(['status'=>$this->selectedStati]);
    }

    public function addToTest($id){
        //attach the given item to the test
        $this->test->items()->attach($id);
        dd($this->test->items);
    }

    public function removeFromTest($id){
        //detach the given item from the test
        $this->test->items()->detach($id);
        
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after attach the item to test collection refresh model to rehydrate it with fresh data like

```
public function addToTest($id){
   //attach the given item to the test
   $this->test->items()->attach($id);
   $this->test->refresh();
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  I hoped it would be something simple like that.  I don't have enough reputation to upvote your answer, but that's definitely the answer.

Comment: Good to hear that, good codding. Just mark this answer at solve

Comment: If I split my left and right lists into two separate livewire components, how can I trigger the other one to refresh.  For example, when I click the button on the left to 'add to the right list', the right list doesn't update.  Can I call a public function in one component from another?

Comment: Use events for that, once add in left emit to right. There is a magic directive for rerender through event listener, ['refresh' => '$refresh']

Comment: Thanks, I found more about it [on this post](https://benborgers.com/posts/livewire-refresh-other-component).